# My dropdown menu hides behind DIV

Tags: css, wordpress, submenu

I am currently using a theme for wordpress called velocity. I am working internally so my website is not online right now. But you can see the live preview of the theme [here](http://themes.damojothemes.com/?theme=velocity_wp).

The problem is that my dropdown menuhided behind this DIV that was automatically created by the theme. I've tried using z-index on both elements, but it did not work.

I didn't change the code of the menu, so right now it must be similar to the live preview on the theme.

The code I assined my DIV (image) was this one:

```
    .title {
background-color:#291d1d;
width:100%;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
background-color:#120404;
opacity:0.7;
padding:20px;
border-radius:5px;
opacity:0.7;
padding-top:40px !important;}
```

Here is a screenshot:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gb4We.png

Any ideas on solving this?

Comment: Can you provide code in Fiddle...?

Comment: Please use the zindex in CSS for menus and the upper div

Comment: Solved id. My DIV is inside a row created automatically by the theme and i put z-index:0 and it was solved!

Answer (score 2):

you can try this :

position:absolute;
z-index:9999999;

Apply this in your drop down UL class

Thanx

Answer (score 0):

Set z-index to a higher value for your menu.

ex: `z-index:999;`

Answer (score 0):

The zindex you provided was not big enough probably you need to check what the z-index of the div is then increment the one from menu if not sure which zindex the image div has
use like a really big number like

```
z-index: 9999999999;
```

Comment: Solved id. My DIV is inside a row created automatically by the theme and i put z-index:0 and it was solved! Thanks!